# Setting dynamic value throughout HTML and CSS in a web resource

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-dynamics

I have an HTML web resource that I am modifying for usage in Dynamics 365. Throughout the resource, a URL is being referenced that I want to replace with a dynamic value that I am retrieving through Javascript, like so:

```
var URL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
```

Throughout the resource, there are items that need to be replaced, such as this (CSS):

```css
.aftertd {
  background: transparent url("REPLACETHIS/_imgs/imagestrips/grid_ctrl_imgs.png?ver=-1792584992") no-repeat scroll -171px -19px;
  height: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 4px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<th>
  <span ng-click="sort('createdon')" class="tdSpanTh">
  Date
    <img ng-show="sortKey=='createdon'" alt="The data is sorted in ascending order on this column" src="REPLACETHIS/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" ng-class="{'ms-crm-List-Sortable ms-crm-Image-Margin ms-crm-ImageStrip-sorting_up':!reverse,'ms-crm-List-Sortable ms-crm-Image-Margin ms-crm-ImageStrip-sorting_down':reverse}" style="visibility:visible;" title="The data is sorted in ascending order on this column">
  </span>
  <span class="aftertd pull-right"></span>
</th>
```

I want to replace the REPLACETHIS value (in the src property above), along with the CSS property value, with the URL variable value.

This is an example of a way that I have tried to do it:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/REPLACETHIS/g, URL);
```

Is there a better way to come at this? The value (REPLACETHIS) is all throughout the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your solution:

```js
var replace = "REPLACETHIS";
var replaceWith = "URL";

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const e = elements[i];
  e.src = e.src.replace(replace, replaceWith);
}

var otherElements = document.querySelectorAll(".aftertd, .otherclass"); //comma seperated selectors
for (var i = 0; i < otherElements.length; i++) {
  const e = otherElements[i];
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
  e.style.background = styles.getPropertyValue("background").replace(replace, replaceWith);
}

//Or more general if you need it:
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  const e = allElements[i];
  for (var attr of ["href", "src"]) { //or other attributes
    var oldVal = e[attr];
    if (oldVal) e[attr] = oldVal.replace(replace, replaceWith);
  }

  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
  for (var prop of ["background", "background-image", "border-image"]) { //or other properties
    var oldVal = styles.getPropertyValue(prop);
    if (oldVal) e.style[prop] = oldVal.replace(replace, replaceWith);
  }
}
```

```css
.aftertd {
  background: transparent url("REPLACETHIS/_imgs/imagestrips/grid_ctrl_imgs.png?ver=-1792584992") no-repeat scroll -171px -19px;
  height: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 4px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<th>
  <span ng-click="sort('createdon')" class="tdSpanTh">
  Date
    <img ng-show="sortKey=='createdon'" alt="The data is sorted in ascending order on this column" src="REPLACETHIS/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" ng-class="{'ms-crm-List-Sortable ms-crm-Image-Margin ms-crm-ImageStrip-sorting_up':!reverse,'ms-crm-List-Sortable ms-crm-Image-Margin ms-crm-ImageStrip-sorting_down':reverse}" style="visibility:visible;" title="The data is sorted in ascending order on this column">
  </span>
  <span class="aftertd pull-right"></span>
</th>
```